# Make Python continue if doesnt find html element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, try-catch

im new to Python, and everything that i know i learned by myself so i have a huge gap in some things like language structure, it would be awsome if someone could help me.

Im building something with selenium and openpyxl and i face a problem, if it doesnt find an element the code stops there, and thats exactly what im trying to bypass without any success. I need to continue if the element not found.

Heres a piece of my currently code, can someone help me how can i do that?

Thanks

```
#distin_city varia
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/ivd-form-field[11]/div[1]/div[1]/ivd-field[1]/div[1]/ivd-select-box-field[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]"))).click()
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/ivd-form-field[11]/div[1]/div[1]/ivd-field[1]/div[1]/ivd-select-box-field[1]/div[1]/div[1]/input[1]")))
element.send_keys(destin_city[:3])
time.sleep(0.2)
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/ivd-form-field[11]/div[1]/div[1]/ivd-field[1]/div[1]/ivd-select-box-field[1]/div[1]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[1]/div[3]/span[1]/div[1]"))).click()
print("DESTINATION CITY - ",destin_city)

#f_payment varia    
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/ivd-form-field[12]/div[1]/div[1]/ivd-field[1]/div[1]/ivd-select-box-field[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]/span[1]"))).click()
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/ivd-form-field[12]/div[1]/div[1]/ivd-field[1]/div[1]/ivd-select-box-field[1]/div[1]/div[1]/input[1]")))
element.send_keys(f_payment[:3])
time.sleep(0.2)
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/ivd-form-field[12]/div[1]/div[1]/ivd-field[1]/div[1]/ivd-select-box-field[1]/div[1]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[1]/div[3]/span[1]/div[1]"))).click()
print("FREIGHT PAYMENT TYPE - ",f_payment)

#currency varia    
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/ivd-form-field[13]/div[1]/div[1]/ivd-field[1]/div[1]/ivd-select-box-field[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]"))).click()
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/ivd-form-field[13]/div[1]/div[1]/ivd-field[1]/div[1]/ivd-select-box-field[1]/div[1]/div[1]/input[1]")))
element.send_keys(currency[:1])
time.sleep(0.2)
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/ivd-form-field[13]/div[1]/div[1]/ivd-field[1]/div[1]/ivd-select-box-field[1]/div[1]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[1]/div[3]/span[1]/div[1]"))).click()
print("CURRENCY - ",currency)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to simply continue with the flow in case the element is not found you can use `try-except` block with `pass` in `except` section.
For example if you want to apply that on

```py
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/ivd-form-field[11]/div[1]/div[1]/ivd-field[1]/div[1]/ivd-select-box-field[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]"))).click()
```

You can do this:

```py
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/ivd-form-field[11]/div[1]/div[1]/ivd-field[1]/div[1]/ivd-select-box-field[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]"))).click()
except Exception:
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and fast reply, i tried that already but i keep getting this error IndentationError:  expected an indented block after 'try' 
i did exactly how you explained but something is missing me, sorry it is a dumb problem

Comment: damm i forgot to align the code..  thats why it wasnt working.. fixed fast.. thanks  and sorry for the previous dumb comment.. im still learning

Comment: No problems. So, now it works correct? Your problem is resolved?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is `try`, `except`. Say you want one or multiple lines to be checked. If anything failed there you can do something else (Or in your example do nothing and `pass`)

You wrap your line(s) with `try`, `except`.

```
try:
   # This is your code
   Do Something 1
   Do something 2
except:
   # This is your code when any line above fails. You can use `pass` to do nothing
   Do something else
```